# Term for 'have to do this first'?

Tags: phrases, terminology

Is there a word for:

'have to do first'

For example I can't do this task because I have a task that I have to do first. That task that I have to do first is a "_____ task".

The second task, which is blocked, is contingent or reliant upon the first. I don't want to call the first task independent or sovereign because the only reason I am doing the first task, is to get to the second. They are still linked, but have to be completed in a certain order.

I thought about using the term 'preceding' but I want to emphasise not just the positioning, but the fact that the first task actively blocks the second.

Comment: The first is a ***prerequisite*** task

Comment: How about "primary task"?

Comment: [yak shaving](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html).

Comment: Preemptory or pre-emptive might suffice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ***critical*** or perhaps ***high-priority*** but those don't indicate that it is a predecessor to your second task, so I think Jim's suggestion of ***prerequisite*** might work for you.

***Requisite*** might be an option as well:

**Requisite**:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Made necessary by particular circumstances or regulations.
>
> ‘the application will not be processed until the requisite fee is
>   paid’

or perhaps ***imperative***:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Of vital importance; crucial.
>
> ‘immediate action was imperative’